# How do I choose one option or the other if user inputs an integer that's not defined?

Tags: python

This program is meant to execute two programs based on user input. If the user inputs 1, it executes program_a. If the user inputs 2, it executes program_b. How do I make it so that if a user inputs any other integer, it randomly chooses between 1 or 2?

```
import random
choice = int(input("Enter the number for your choice: "))
r = random.randint(1,2)
if choice == 1:
  program_a()
elif choice == 2:
  program_b()
else:
  choice = r
```

Comment: `random.choice([1,2])`

Comment: Two equal signs does not do assignment

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to use [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) to randomly choose between a list of data.

So, in your case:

```
import random
val = random.choice([1, 2])
```